# What is the radius of the circle?

Tags: geometry

[image: circle radius]

Please help with this grade nine math problem.  How does one calculate the radius if the two sides of the right angle triangle are 85cm.  The sides of the triangle are tangent to the circle.

Comment: Maybe you should state that the 3 sides of the triangle are tangent to the circle as they look.

Comment: Take the center of the circle and join it to all the vertices. Now you will have three triangle, whose heights would be the radius. Hence, if you add it all, you will find that the radius is area of the triangle divided by the semiperimeter.

Comment: Thanks for the help and hints.  I'm actually a parent trying to help a grade nine student with her math, and honestly I can't recall my geometry from 25 years ago.  Is there another way to solve this problem as I don't think they have learned about semiperimeter I am guessing (might be wrong here - I will double check).

Comment: Light Bulb!  The old brain hard drive finally kicked in with help from the hints provided.  Using Karolis' diagram and calculating AB from AB^2=85^2+85^2 making AB=120.21, dividing AB by 2 to get AD = 60.11, we know AD = AF so FC=85-AF which is FC=85-60.11= 24.89 cm as the radius of the circle.

Comment: Well, semiperimeter is no spooky thing at all, just the perimeter divided by 2, which anyone can easily understand.

Comment: There certainly appears to be more than one way to skin the cat.  The trick is to find the preferred method that matches the math level taught!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Hint.** $AD = DB = AF$ and $FC = OE = r$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It's useful to realize that the "left" and "right" radia, as drawn in the above picture, will be parallel to the respective cathetae.

Then you get:

$$C=\sqrt{A^2+A^2}=\sqrt{2}A$$

The height of the triangle is then:

$$h=\sqrt{A^2-\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{A^2-\frac{A^2}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}A$$

Define x-axis along the base of the triangle and y-axis along the height.
Unit vectors at a 45° angle to the x-axis are given by:

$$\vec{u}_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left({1}\atop{1}\right)~~~~~,~~~~~\vec{u}_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left({1}\atop{-1}\right)$$
You can check $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}=1$.

Now use that the distance from any of the two 45° angles to the two nearest spots where the circle touches the triangle is the same, namely $C/2=A/\sqrt{2}$.

With this you can establish a vectorial relation between the following vectors:

$$h\vec{e}_y+\left(A-\frac{C}{2}\right)\vec{u}_2=R\vec{e}_y+R\vec{u}_1$$

Where $\vec{e}_y=(0,1)$ is the unit vector along the y-axis. This gives you two equations.

The y-axis equation is:

$$h-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(A-\frac{C}{2}\right)=R+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}R\\\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(A-\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)R\\\frac{A}{2}=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)R\\R=\frac{A}{2+\sqrt{2}}$$

The x-axis equation is:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(A-\frac{C}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}R\\\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)A=R\\R=\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2+\sqrt{2}}A\\R=\frac{2-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}-1}{2+\sqrt{2}}A\\R=\frac{A}{2+\sqrt{2}}$$

Both answers properly agree, so that the world is a happy and sunny place.

Comment: Not in Antarctica, I guess.

Comment: My palms are getting all sweaty just looking at some of these replies.  Brings back some bad memories of intermediate calculus back in university.  And to think I had a math minor back then ....(shivers!)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** $A=rs$

where $A=\text{area},r=\text{inradius},s=\text{semiperimeter}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\ (=85{\rm cm})$ be the length of the legs and $r$ the radius of the circle. Then
$${1\over2}\bigl(\sqrt{2}a\bigr)+r=a\ ,$$
which implies
$$r=\left(1-{\sqrt{2}\over2}\right)\>a\ .$$